# Why doesn't LaTeX include my bibtex bibliography in the references section?

Tags: bibtex

How can I include the `.bib` file in the latex file. I have tried:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibilographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\include{reference}
\end{document}
```

Opened a new file whose chapter heading is Reference as:

```
\chapter{Reference}
\bibilography{Ref.bib}
```

This is not showing any results included in the `Ref.bib` file in bibtex. I have used `Jabref` to create a `.bib` file.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to add citations to the items in your bibliography. If you want every citation from Ref.bib included, use `\nocite{*}` right before the `\bibliography` line.

Also there is no need for the line `\chapter{Reference}`. By default, a new chapter will be created for the bibliography anyway. By default, that chapter will be named "Bibliography". If you want it named "Reference" or something else, then use  `\renewcommand{\bibname}{Reference}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure what your problem is.

If you want to **create a bibliography** it is not enaugh to inclued the `bib`-file you also need to run `(pdf)latex` - `biblatex` - `(pdf)latex` maby more than one time. See any better beginners guide for more information or consult Google. If you just want to **add the bibliography heading to the ToC** use `\addcontentsline{toc}{<sectin/chapter/…>}{References}` or use a KOMA-Script (e. g. class `scrreprt` instead of `report`) and its `bibliography=totoc`-option, see the manual for more information.

Answer (score 2):

@Reshma: You seem to have a couple of typos in your example file -- the commands should be `bibliographystyle{plainnat}` and `\bibliography{ref}`. (You have `bibilography` both times.) Note that you do *not* need to create a separate chapter before starting in the bibliography: LaTeX will do this for you when it encounters the command `\bibliography{ref}` -- assuming that the bib file is called `ref.bib`, of course.